# LiPo charger MCP73831 does not light an LED with it's STAT pin when done charging

Tags: lipo

I'm trying to charge a LiPo with MCP73831 with 2 LEDs for status. I have an amber LED `D1` which is on when `VUSB` is getting power from the USB connector, which means that it's charging. And a green LED `D2` that should also light up when the battery is fully charged.

I'm having no luck getting the green LED `D2` to light up when the charge is complete. I can see that the USB draw drops to near zero, and after being plugged into USB power for hours, the green LED will never light up. It's clearly done charging and the battery output voltage measures 4.2V, which is expected for a fully charged single cell LiPo battery.

Interestingly, when I poked around with the multimeter I got the green LED to illuminate. When I measured the voltage between `GND` and `VBAT` the green LED turned on while the probes were in contact with the circuit. When I removed the multimeter probes, the green LED immediately turned off.

So two questions:

1. Why doesn't the `STAT` pin output `HIGH` when charging is complete as the datasheet claims it should? (which should light the green LED `D2`)
2. Why does measuring the voltage between `GND` and `VBAT` cause the STAT pin to output `HIGH`?
3. Does the multimeter measuring between `GND` and `VBAT` effectively place a high Ohm resistor between the two? And if so, would that fix this? Why?

[image: Charging schematic]

Links to relevant things:

- [MCP78381 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf)
- These are [the specific ICs](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=MCP73831T-3ACI%2fOTvirtualkey57940000virtualkey579-MCP73831T-3ACIOT).
- [These are the batteries](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1317)
- [Full circuit and PCB here](https://upverter.com/Squeegy/77b7e5d93e147c83/Chakra-Pendant/)

Comment: Could you provide the exact product number of the MCP78381 IC? There are numerous of voltage options on these for different kind of batteries. Maybe you have one for a higher voltage than your finished cell voltage? Just a guess.

Comment: These are [the specific ICs](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=MCP73831T-3ACI%2fOTvirtualkey57940000virtualkey579-MCP73831T-3ACIOT). And [this is the battery](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1317).

Comment: Alex - see my added comments to Dejvid's answer (and +2 effective upvote :-). | Your IC is probably a 73831 as claimed -  check that it is not a 73882 as they are functionally very similar but my comments re STAT pin would then apply. || Easy check. Remove battery and put as large an electrolytic capacitor as is available in its place. The charger should charge it to 4.3x volts and stop and the LED should work as you hope. You MAY need to trickle the cap up to about 3V with a high value resistor to V+ to get it going as it will probably initially otherwise see it as 'no battery present'...

Comment: Once it is charged load it with a resistor, vcap will fall charging will restart , remove load and it will re-cycle. ||| I now think that Dejvid is probably correct BECAUSE the battery probably contains a protection IC to prevent overvoltage charging. If it did not, and some do not, it may well be dead by now. || Last important point.- Check the USB charging voltage input - it needs to be about 5.4V minimum at the input point. It should be above that, but do check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MCP73831T-3ACI/OT has a VREG of 4.35V.
Your battery is finished charging at 4.2V.

The STAT pin will never go high since the regulator thinks that the charging is not finished.

Comment: Did I purchase the incorrect version of this IC? or did I fail to program it properly with the `PROG` resistor somehow?

Comment: Yep. I think MCP73831T-2ACI/OT would work. It is also on Mouser.

Comment: Interesting... I guess that's it then. Was I damaging this battery charging it at 4.35V when it's 4.2V at maximum charge?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 Amended comment. This answer is essentially wrong - but you make an excellent and important point. The major issues is that he shows the STAT LED connected wrongly - if this is how he has really done it it will never light. You are correct that the charger voltage is higher than the battery data sheet says is correct - BUT it will almost certainly charge OK to that voltage - or burst into flames :-) :-(.

Comment: Sorry, but the major problem is that he is trickle charging a Litium based cell to a over spec voltage. The STAT connection is fine.

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 - I just upvoted your answer - so you get an effective +2 :-) BUT that's because I was (probably) wrong about STAT and not re battery V per se. Because ....
- Hopefully they have sold him a 83831 and not a 73832 - they are very similar BUT the (probable) reason the LED is shown as it is in the example is that  it is the only way it will work with an ...832 as the STAT line is open drain  and not push pull. So checking what Mouser sent him is a good start. Next ... | I totally agree (and always did) with your statement that the charge voltage is too high for the battery used. ...

Comment: ... However, a LiPo (or LiIon) cell should continue to trickle on up to possible destruction if too high a charge voltage is applied. Somewhere not far above 4.2V you start to plate out metallic Lithium and nasty things happen - but there is not usually anything in the battery proper stopping this. HOWEVER the battery should contain a protection circuit and that may well be preventing charge termination. Well done the manufacturers if that is the case. Either way - he should **certainly** use a lower voltage  charger. | Note - the realisation that it MAY be a protection IC that is making ...

Comment: ... the difference only occurred as I was writing the above paragraph. I'm aware that LiPos  do not obligingly sit at 4.2V if you try to charge them so I found fault with your claim without spotting that the extra circuitry may be the reason. So that probably makes you effectively correct all round :-). Mentioning a protection circuit would be a bonus.

Comment: No problem, he wrote that he had a 73831 so I just assumed that he had one of those when I checked the datasheet. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem MAY BE that your STAT LED is connected wrongly.
This depends on the IC actually supplied.  The 73831 will work as you have shown. The almost functionally identical 73832 will not. Odds are your IC is as specified, but checking would be wise.

---

Dejvid is correct that a lower voltage option of the IC should be used - but the battery would almost certainly charge to the higher voltage if it was a bare battery. After reassessing Dejvid's comments I realised that the battery was probably being protected by an internal overcharge protection circuit. I have just rechecked the battery data sheet and see that they say "with PCM" - ie protection module. This is what has saved your battery. Some Asian sourced batteries which claim to have a PCM fitted do not have one. It seems that yours does ! :-).

The -3 version of the IC has min/typical/max Vterminate voltages of 4.317 / 4.35 / 4.383.
These voltages are too high for most LiPo batteries and will in many cases cause low cycle lifetimes and in some cases **may** cause spectacular flaming destruction. The PCM protects against this but should not be relied on.

[**Battery data sheet here**](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/1317/C1515_-_Li-Polymer_402025_150mAh_3.7V_with_PCM.pdf)
Note stated end point voltage of 4.2V. This is standard and should not be exceeded.

Comment: The truth table says STAT will go high = to VDD through the  upper transistor of STAT push-pull stage. Shouldn't this light his LED? :)

Comment: That's one way to connect the led. It would be on while charging and off when done. That's not what I'm after though. The real problem here is that STAT should be 0V when charging and ~4.2V when charged. That should light the LED. So, while not exactly like the "typical" application it should work as wired, assuming I ordered the correct part that terminates charging at 4.2 V.

Comment: I guess you're commenting on Russels interpretation. Your wiring is perfectly fine Alex.